# How to create custom dialog which contain different UI in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to show any screen as a dialog. This is my main requirement, but if this is not possible second thing is: I have to create one custom dialog which contain different UI.

From above any one of requirement I have to fulfill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Coding4Fun Windows Phone Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) contains classes that you can use to display a modal/popup prompt for displaying information or getting input from the user.